# Filtering my matrix in R

Tags: r

I don't know exactly what is going on, because when I attempt what I want to do in a simple manner at the prompt, it works fine, but when I do in my function it simply doesn't work.

This is the simple version

```
p
    x  y
1   1  2
2   2  3
3   3  4
4   4  5
5   5  6
6   6  7
7   7  8
8   8  9
9   9 10
10 10 11
> p[,2][y!=2]
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

And this is my function

```
corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {

  #setwd(directory)

  # Correlations of all the monitors

  corr_all_monit <- data.frame(id = 1:332, corrs = 0)

  for(i in 1:332){


# Reading the files in the directory

idi <- paste(formatC(i, width=3, flag="0"), "csv", sep=".")
onedataset <- read.csv(idi)

# Eliminating the NAs

onedataset <- onedataset[complete.cases(onedataset),]

# Getting the length of the filtered data

monitor_length <- length(onedataset[,1])

# Doing the correlation of the data which surpass the threshold

if(monitor_length > threshold){
  corr_all_monit[i,2] <- cor(onedataset[,2],onedataset[,3])
}    

  }

  # Picking up only the correlations which surpass the threshold

  return(corr_all_monit[,2][corrs != 0])

}
```

When I try to run it, I get:

```
source("corr.R")
corr("/Users/Fanaro/specdata",150)
Error in corr("/Users/Fanaro/specdata", 150) : object 'corrs' not found
```

Comment: `p[,2][y!=2]` shouldn't work. R doesn't know what's `y` unless you have some other `y` vector in your global environment or you used `attach`

Comment: oh, I composed p with 2 vectors, x and y, which are its columns. It might be that then.

Comment: I changed the last line in my function to 

return(corr_all_monit[,2]["corrs" != 0]) but now the values with 0 are not being filtered :/

Comment: This isn't reproducible and we can't really test your function.

Comment: The main problem is only the last line. I already tested everything and it works till the last line. I want to create a vector with all the elements from the second column of corr_all_monit which are different from 0. Granted the second column of corr_all_monit is named corrs.

Comment: `corr_all_monit[corr_all_monit$corrs != 0, 2]` should do. you don't need `return` btw.